Finding a new MST for $G(V,E)$ after connecting a new vertex
Let $G(V, E)$ be an undirected, connected, graph. We have a weight function $w: E \to R$, and let $T$ be an MST of $G$.
Suppose we connect a vertex $v$ to $G$ with at least one edge, and let's call the new graph $G^*$. We want to find an MST of $G^*$, with a time complexity of $O(|V|\log|V|)$.
My attempt:
I know that $v$ is connected by at most $|V|$ edges to $G$, and since $T$ contains all of $G$'s vertices, and has $|V| - 1$ edges.
Let's define $A$ is {all of $v$'s edges}. Running Kruskal on the graph that contains $T$'s edges and $A$ gives us an MST for $G^*$. Since Kruskal's runtime is $O(|E|\log|E|)$, and since we have at most $2|V|-1$ edges, it satisfies the time complexity.
I'm unsure how to prove its correctness - I receive a spanning tree, but can there be a more minimal tree?

This is exactly one step of Prim's algorithm. There we already have a minimum spanning tree of some subset of vertices $V'$ then we consider new vertex $v$ and it's incident edges along with the already computed MST for $V'$ to obtain a new MST for $V' \cup \{v\}$. You can refer to proof of correctness of Prim's algorithm for more details (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm).
